# How to deal with the security role delegate in power app

Tags: powerapps

I got a question, we create a power app, and based on the security roles. different users can access different screens, the problem is that how to deal with the delegate? for example, user A could access the admin screen, but A is delegate to B, B should act as A. How to process this? any sustainable ideas?

Comment: kindly explain further, is this a model/canvas app? what type of data sources do you use? how did you implement the roles?

Comment: Hi @mmikesy90, this is a canvas app, and data is stored in both sharepoint and dataverse, I just want to explore what is the sustainable way?